# SwiftUI:Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type?

Tags: ios, swift, rest, swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var user: GitHubUser?
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            
            AsyncImage(url: URL(string: user?.avatarUrl ?? "")) { image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            } placeholder: {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                
            }
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            
        
            Text(user?.login ?? " Username")
                .bold()
                .font(.title3)
            
            Text(user?.bio ?? "This is where gitHub bio will go")
                .padding()
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .task{
            do{
                user = try await getUser()
            } catch GHError.invalidURL {
                print("invalid IRL")
            } catch GHError.invalidResponse {
                print("invalid response")
            } catch GHError.invalidData {
                print("invalid data")
            }catch {
                print("unknown")
            }
        }
        
        func getUser() async throws -> GitHubUser {
            let endpoint = "https://api.github.com/users/Username"
            guard let url = URL(string: endpoint) else {
                throw GHError.invalidURL
                
            }
            
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                throw GHError.invalidResponse
            }
            
            do {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
                
                return try decoder.decode(GitHubUser.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                throw GHError.invalidData
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    struct GitHubUser: Codable {
        let login: String
        let avatarUrl: String
        let bio: String
    }
    
    enum GHError: Error {
        case invalidURL
        case invalidResponse
        case invalidData
    }
}
```

I already try at `@ViewBuilder` from the troubleshooting, the error keep popping out.

I try to look from other same error but could not still find the solution.
`var body: some View`, the error show in this line.
The error said:

> SwiftUI:Function declares an opaque return type, but has no return statements in its body from which to infer an underlying type?

Comment: Move the function `getUser() async throws -> GitHubUser` outside of `body`

Comment: Your nesting is a bit messed up and your ```body``` includes a ```func```. The closing brace right at the end of your example needs to be moved up so that it comes before the function ```getUser```.